# What is the syntax for using the restrict keyword for a 2d array function parameter?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameters, restrict-qualifier

I have an array declared in my main function:
`float A[n][n];`

My goal is to pass it to a function with the `restrict` keyword:
`void func(int n, float restrict A[][n])`

I tried the syntax above, but I am not getting the optimization in running time that I am expecting. I have also seen this syntax for 1d arrays:
`void func(int n, float A[restrict])`

Comment: There need not be any change in running time. Why'd you expect there to be any?

Comment: I expected there to be a reduction in running time because I read that the compiler performs extra checks for pointer aliasing including array references in function parameters. By telling the compiler not to do these checks, I expected a reduction in running time.

Comment: You have only *one* pointer argument. The restrict means that it cannot point to any other `float` *array* that you could use within the function, or that any other outer *float pointer* that you use cannot point to an array element. If there are not even such pointers being used there cannot conceivably be any optimization effects.

Comment: Thank you. But I actually have two more float arrays being passed to func, so I think it may apply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer can be restrict. All below forms are equivalent:

```
void func(int n, float A[restrict n][n]);
void func(int n, float A[restrict][n]);
void func(int n, float (* restrict A)[n]);
```